# assigning to list[:] using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, slice

from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207461/8074522
I'm trying to find the difference between using

```
somelist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
somelist = [x for x in somelist if x>4]
and 
somelist[:] = [x for x in somelist if x>4]
```

in his answer, he is saying

> Or, by assigning to the slice somelist[:], you can mutate the existing
>   list to contain only the items you want:

"to contain only" < I can use assign to the somelist without slicing.

So what's the need of somelist[:] [here?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207461/8074522)

Comment: Assigning to `somelist` **does not** change the list that that name used to refer to, whereas assigning to `somelist[:]` does. Which is right for your case will depend on the details of your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instruction like `somelist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` creates a **new list** and
**assigns** it (the whole list) to your variable (`somelist`).

The second case, `somelist = [x for x in somelist if x>4]` is just **filtering**.
The `for` loop assigns each element from this list to a temporary variable `x`.

Then (inside this loop) `if` checks whether this (current) element meets
some condition, in your case, whether it is greater than 4.

Only if it is, this element is added to the new array, which finally will be
assigned to `somelist`.

And now what is the difference between **plain assignment** (just to `somelist`)
and the **slice assignment** ( to `somelist[:]`).

Imagine that initially there was `otherList` and you created your `somelist`
using plain assignment: `somelist = otherList`.

Actually, no second list has then been created, but `somelist` may be regarded as
another "pointer to" that first list.

In other words, both `otherList` and `somelist` point to **the same** internal
object (in this case, array).

Then, later in your code, if you used `somelist[:] = ...` you write new content
to **the same** internal object, so this new content is visible also using `otherList`
(e.g. in other part of your code).

But if you used plain assignment (`somelist = ...`), then:

- There is created a **new** internal object (array) and `somelist` points
  just to it.
- The **old** content is still visible as `otherList`.

So as *jonrsharpe* pointed out, the decision which option to use depends
on what your application really needs.

In the simplest case, if you have no other variable pointing to the "old"
array, you can use plain assignment (IMHO a more natural option) and the
old array (now with no reference from any other variable) will be garbage
collected.

Comment: @leo he said "Replaces the list in-place and keeping the same object.. it was not clear till you explained in better way .. Thanks for all of you , Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

@jonsharpe gave a terse answer in the comment, but to illustrate this clearly:

Assign a new list. Loses the reference to the old list object and creates a **new** one:

```
>>> lst1 = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]
>>> lst2 = lst1
>>> lst1 = [[7,8,9]]
>>> lst1 is lst2
False
>>> lst1
[[7, 8, 9]]
>>> lst2
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Assign to slice. **Replaces** the list (or a part of the list, depending on what the slice is) in-place, keeping the same object.

```
>>> lst1 = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]
>>> lst2 = lst1
>>> lst1[:] = [[7,8,9]]
>>> lst1 is lst2
True
>>> lst1
[[7, 8, 9]]
>>> lst2
[[7, 8, 9]]
```